# PlayStore App download size shows wrong comparing to play console

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, android-app-bundle

PlayStore app size shows more than the play console app download size.

Recently we released our new version to PlayStore showing 39MB size but in the play console, I have checked all my last 4 releases including this new release showing the app download size is 19MB only but in PlayStore it's showing more. Not sure what is the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On the internal testing track, the APKs are not compressed and can thus be significantly bigger.

Consider reaching out to Play Developers support if you see this happening on other tracks persistently.